# Contact form php troubles

Tags: php, contact-form

This is the code i use, when i input information into the form the mail sends incomplete emails like if i add 1 to all fields and email name etc it shows:

From:
 Email:
 Tale:
 Sms:
 Data:
 LevrandÃ¸r:
 Ekstra informasjon:

So im lacking the information.

```
 <?php 

   $name = $_POST['f_name'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $tale = $_POST['tale'];
   $sms = $_POST['sms'];
   $data = $_POST['data'];
   $levrandor = $_POST['levrandor'];
   $ekstra = $_POST['ekstra'];
   $formcontent="From: $name \n Email: $email \n Tale: $tale \n Sms: $sms \n Data: $data \n Levrandør: $levrandor \n Ekstra informasjon: $ekstra";
   $recipient = "post@mobilavtalen.no";
   $subject = "Melding fra bruker.";
   $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";

   mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");

   if(mail){

   header('Location: thanks.html');

   }else{ echo "Email ble ikke sendt";}


    ?>
```

HTML form:

```
<div class="form_area text-left">
            <form id="contact-form" action="mail.php" method="post">
                <fieldset>
                    <label>Navn:</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="">
                    <label>E-mail: (Må fylles inn)</label>
                    <input type="email" placeholder="" required>
                    <label>Forbruk pr mnd (Må fylles inn):</label>
                    <label>Tale:</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="" required>
                    <label>Sms:</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="" required>
                    <label>Data:</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="" required>
                    <label>Levrandør:</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="" required>
                    <label>Ekstra informasjon:</label>
                    <textarea rows="3"></textarea><br>
                    <!--<input type="submit" id="submit_button" class="btn" value="Send">-->
                    <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit_button">Send</button>
              </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: so you want to include the posted data in the email?

Comment: The PHP code seems OK, probably an error in the HTML form. Can you post the code for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the name property on the form fields.

The `name` property should be the same as the `key` you use in the `$_POST` array. Like this for example:

```
<input type="text" name="f_name" placeholder="">
```

And in PHP

```
$name = $_POST['f_name'];
```

You can read more about the `$_POST` array [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).

Comment: Og god kveld forresten ;)

Comment: So they need to match? God kveld du :)

Comment: That's correct. The `$_POST` array is indexed by the `name` properties in the form.

Comment: Ok so it worked on all except the "ekstra informasjon" part at the bottom.

Comment: And you set the `name` attribute on the textarea to `ekstra`?

Comment: <label>Ekstra informasjon:</label>
     <textarea rows="3" name="ekstra"></textarea><br> 
     <!--<input type="submit" id="submit_button" class="btn" value="Send">-->
     <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit_button">Send</button>

Comment: Looks OK, double check that you use `$_POST['ekstra']` and `$ekstra` everywhere in your PHP code.

Comment: As far as i can see it's used everywhere.

Comment: Could it be that i misplaced the name att within the wrong part?

Comment: Did you get it to work? Looks like the `name` attribute is in the correct place to me.

Comment: Strange, maybe you should post another question about why the textarea doesn't work with your updated code, there's probably just a small mistake somewhere. Please accept my answer since it helped you with the name attribute problem that was your initial problem.